# How to prove this equality about Eulerian numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, eulerian-numbers

I want to prove the following equality where $A(k,m)$ is the Eulerian number :

$$\forall k\ge0,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}n^k x^k = \frac{\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}A(k,m)x^{m+1}}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

I previously proved that the two following identities are equivalent.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge0}a_nt^n &= \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{k}\beta_jt^j}{(1-t)^{k+1}} \\
\forall n\ge0 , a_n &= \sum_{j=0}^{k}\beta_j\binom{n+k-j}{k}
\end{align*}

It is advised to use this previous result to prove the equality. Since I only had a combinatorial definition of the Eulerian numbers, I managed to prove the closed-form expression : $A(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}(-1)^k \binom{n+1}{k} (m+1-k)^n.$ So by using the closed-form expression for Eulerian numbers and the previous equivalence I need to prove that :

$$\forall n\ge1 , n^k = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=0}^{j} (-1)^i\binom{k+1}{i}(j-i)^k\binom{n+k-j}{k}$$

But I have no idea how to go further, I don't see how it is an improvement to prove the original equality.

Comment: Precisely this question (modulo a change of summation index) was asked and proved at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130184/) (two different proofs).

Comment: I will take a deeper look at it later, but it seems to be what I need. Thank you !